# Best Practices on return for CRUD

Tags: java, crud

What are (if there are) the best practices for returning objects on CRUD operations. In my case, for Java.

For example, for CREATE I supose to return the object, its ID...?

Comment: The 'Best Practices' for a CRUD app are certainly important, but not always as important as the 'Best Practices' for when your CRUD app runs into errors...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

- *create* - created object. I know, I know it's typically the same object, but it's both convenient and elegant.
- *update* - also return the same object. In some frameworks like JPA updated object can be a different instance then the one provided.
- *restore* - obviously the object you want to restore. If you are restoring a list, consider implementing paging - taking offset/max and returning list wrapped in a `Page` object with some extra metadata like the total number of entries.
- *delete* - there is nothing to return here, `void`.

Comment: Create can often result in a new database generated ID, so a returned copy of the created object can be useful.

Comment: I think that you should edit _crate_ for _create_ (a small thing anyway). For **DELETE**, isn't would be nice to return a boolean if deleting goes fine or not?

Comment: @elecay: typo, thx. Wrt. *delete*: it depends on the semantics of your service. If you are sure that the object you are deleting exists, stick to `void` and throw an exception if it was not found. If your service accepts object that might already not exist, `boolean` is fine ([similar to Java collections](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#remove(java.lang.Object))).

Comment: More than 6 years after, I think is time to accept this answer. Merry Christmas.

Comment: R=restore? when did we change that CRUD convention

Answer (score 0):

There's not really a defined set of best practices, but here's a list of how I've used CRUD procs:

Create: Pass in no data or some data (e.g. for a new user a name, address, email address, etc.) and get a new object or primary key of the newly inserted record.

Read: Pass on something which can identify a single record or sets of records (e.g. most likely a primary key like a person's id or email address).

Update: Pass in all pieces of data which are to be updated. If the piece of data is NOT to be updated, make sure you allow null values to be passed in and if the value is null, skip updating that column.

Delete: Pass in an identifier (e.g. id or email address for a person) and get nothing (void) returned or a boolean indicating that the delete was successful.